# what is the root note of D/A

Tags: theory, chord-theory, songwriting

i came across a weird chord, D/A. but is the root note of this chord D or A? A is being played as a bass and is lower.

Answer (score 1):

The root of a chord is not always the same as the lowest sounding note. When the lowest sounding note is the root, we say the chord is in *root position*. When it's not, we say the chord is *inverted* or is an *inversion*.

Chord names with slashes are inversions. In this case, the lowest sounding note is A, but the root is still D because the rest of the notes are D and F#, and D F# and A form a major triad with a root of D.

Comment: Note that with D/A the F# and D notes can be in any order, and there may or may not be octave copies of all three notes played in higher registers.